# Polymer - Atribuir um valor padrão para uma content tag

Tags: javascript, polymer

Eu estou criando um elemento Polymer com essa estrutura::

```
  <template>

    <style>
      ...
    </style>

    <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h1"></content>
    </div>
    <content></content>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({});

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Para atribuir um valor padrão para o atributo `src` do elemento `<content select="img">` eu adicionei o script:

```
Polymer({
   srcimg: 'default-picture.png'
});
```

Quando renderizado no browser o atributo é preenchido no  shadow DOM mas não no elemento `<img>` dentro do elemento `<e-card>`. Como fazer o elemento `<img>` assumir o valor atribuido pelo script caso ele não seja atribuído deliberadamente?

Answer (score 1):

João Paulo, não acredito ser boa prática alterar conteúdo do "insertion point" à partir de seu componente pois isto destroi o encapsulamento. O "insertion point" serve para implementar injeção de dependência e permitir que o cliente especifique conteúdo a ser inserido em pontos definidos do layout do componente. Seguramente deve existir outra forma de implementar o que você deseja sem ferir o principio do encapsulamento ao qual o Polymer se propõe a fornecer no seu framework.

De qualquer forma segue o código para acessar e manipular a imagem substituindo o valor do atributo src.

**OBS:** testei apenas no **GoogleChrome**

O que você precisa é deste script:

```
<script>
  Polymer('my-element', {
    srcimg: 'img/network_workgroup.svg',
    ready: function() {
      var myEl = document.querySelector('my-element > img');
      myEl.src = this.srcimg;
    }
  });
</script>
```

O código completo aparece abaixo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <script src="../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body fullbleed layout vertical>

  <polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="">
    <template>
      <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      .card-header {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      polyfill-next-selector { content: '.card-header h5'; }
      .card-header ::content h5 {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: red;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      polyfill-next-selector { content: 'h2'; }
      ::content h2 {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: teal; 
        color: white; 
        padding: 5px 5px;
      }
      </style>

      <div class="card-header">
        <content select="img"></content>
        <br />
        <content select="h5"></content>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div style="color: gold">
        <content></content>
        Finalização do Componente - Footer
        <hr />
      </div>

    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('my-element', {
        srcimg: 'img/network_workgroup.svg',
        ready: function() {
          var myEl = document.querySelector('my-element > img');
          myEl.src = this.srcimg;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <my-element>
    <h2>Teste do Elemento</h2>
    <h5>fig. 1 - network workgroup example</h5>
    <img src="" width="200px" height="200px"></img>
  </my-element>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
      // se necessário faça tratamento adicional no cliente do componente
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```